# Xubuntu 14.04 How to use two keyboard shortcuts to change keyboard layout

Tags: xubuntu

I was used to have two keyboard layouts Czech and English. But when I wanted to type any character from another keyboard layout I didn't want to change the whole layout. So I like to press just  and while pressing  the layout is switched. On the other hand when I write longer text I wat to switch layout with

How to achieve double key for switch keyboard layout?
One key while pressed and the other one toggle change.

Answer (score 4):

In xfce I found there is only one possibility to set switch layout key in GUI settings, but if you want to use two keys fro switch layout you must edit it in Settings editor:

In `xfce4-settings-editor` find `keyboard-layout/Default/XkbOptions/Group` and insert> `grp:alt_caps_toggle,grp:rctrl_switch`

this will use alt+caps to swtich layout
and right ctrl will switch layout only while pressed